# How return an List<object> if a mvc form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an `USER` and a `CAR` class.

I know how build an `USER CREATE` form, naming simple element same as the field on db (like name, phonenumber) so on SUBMIT the Action method get every element and I can save it to db.

Now on the CREATE form I also want user add CARS, and on SUBMIT send List.

How I do that?

For example I can return a collection like this Or return one car element, creating an input for each car property.

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/UpdateInts">
     <input type="text" name="cars" value="1" />
     <input type="text" name="cars" value="4" />
     <input type="text" name="cars" value="2" />
     <input type="text" name="cars" value="8" />
     <input type="submit" />
</form>

public ActionResult UpdateInts(ICollection<int> cars) {
  SaveMethod(cars);
}
```

But how I do to receive

```
public ActionResult UpdateInts(ICollection<Car> myCars) {
  SaveMethod(myCars);
}
```

Cuurently Im using [jQuery EasyUI grid](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid12.php) To add cars, make and model during the create user page.

Comment: So you want to save a user and a car on one submit?

Comment: one user and N cars in one submit

Comment: You need to generate controls with the correct name attributes with indexers - `name="[0].Make"`, `name="[0].Model"`, `name="[1].Make"`, `name="[1].Model"` etc. Some options to consider for dynamically creating new items in a view [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using raw form data. So there was no need of passing a model to the view (No a MVC pattern). This is not the best solution but a working solution. I will update soon if I come up with better solution.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCars(int a = 0){
        var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var form = Request.Form;
        for (int i = 1; i < form.Count; i ++ )
        {
            context.Cars.Add(new Car() { Name = form[i] });
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
        return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Car</h4>
        <hr />
        <input type="text" name="car1" value="car1" />
        <input type="text" name="car2" value="car2" />
        <input type="text" name="car3" value="car3" />
        <input type="text" name="car4" value="car4" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**Model**

```
public class Car{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a view model of your user with collection of cars inside.

```
public clas ViewModel
{
    //User properties
    public IEnumerable<Car> Cars {get; set;}
}
```

The use this View Model in your View for Create/Edit:

```
@model ViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    //User Editor Here

    @for(int i=0; i <= Model.Cars.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Cars[i])
    }
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

And the action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateInts(ViewModel viewModel) {
  //Get your user and cars here and save them
}
```

Comment: That look good for Update. But I think I can make it work for Create with Model.Car.add(newCar) before post.

Comment: When you submit, you can create your user and fill its collection of cars. Then save/update to your db.